# Como solucionar: Cannot read property add of undefined ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha

Tengo una aplicación **ExtJS/Html** en la que estoy trabajando y me he  encontrando con el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

La función sobre la que estoy trabajando es la siguiente:

```
function panelTab(){
    a = "Details";
    b = "<iframe src='https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.html#method-getCmp' width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>";
    c = "Frame";
    Ext.getCmp('layout').add({
            title    : a,
            html     : b,
            iconCls  : c,
            closable : true,
          }).show();
}
```

No se exactamente lo que está pasando.

Estoy consultando la documentación [aquí](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.html#method-getCmp)

Cualquier ayuda sería increíble.

Comment: Al parecer no encuentra el componente 'layout' y por eso te retonar `undefined` en ` Ext.getCmp('layout')`

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza El componente `layout` si existe, hay otra forma de obtener lo del elemento ?